# Cannot login with correct password after fresh install: the disk is full

Tags: login

I've installed CAE Linux (**Ubuntu 16.04**) with USB-stick. I cannot login with GUI mode with my login and password, but it is possible to login another (CLI) terminal. And it is possible to login with GUI mode with Guest Session.

I suspect the reason is there is no free hard disk space. Please, guide me a proper steps. What I have to do? I wonder something is wrong with swap file.

```
:~$ uname -a
Linux ivan-imedia-S1800 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64
```

```
:~$ vi .bashrc
E297: Write error in swap file
E303: Unable to open swap file for ".bashrc", recovery impossible
```

```
:~$ free -h
       total  used free shared buff/cache available
 Mem:   2.9G   249M 1.9G   10M    767M       2.6G
Swap:   2.3G     0B 2.3G
```

```
:~$ df -h
Filesystem Size Use% Mounted on
udev 1.5G 0% /dev
tmpfs 301M 2% /run
/dev/sdb8 16G 100% /
tmpfs 1.5G 1% /dev/shm
tmpfs 5.0M 1% /run/lock
tmpfs 1.5G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none 1.5G 1% /tmp/guest-wgi1qc
tmpfs 301M 1% /run/user/997
tmpfs 301M -% /run/user/1000
```

```
:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465 GiB

Device Boot Id Type
sda1 * 7 HPFS/NTFS
sda2   7 HPFS/NTFS
sda3   f W95 Ext'd
sda4   7 HPFS/NTFS
sda5   7 HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sdb: 233 GiB

Device Boot Id Type
sdb1   83 Linux
sdb2 * f  W95 Ext'd
sdb5   7  HPFS/NTFS
sdb6   7  HPFS/NTFS
sdb7   82 Linux swap / Solaris
sdb8   83 Linux
```

Comment: The swap file has not problem. Your issue isn't lack of ram (which swap would help), it's about lack of space on the root partition. You can login with a guest account because nothing is written to the disk on login.

Comment: Your root file system is full. `/dev/sdb8 16G 100% /` Move some data elsewhere or delete some data. To do this you can log in on a virtual console or boot a live Linux system and mount `/dev/sdb8`.